# How can pass a decimal value with Razor in a JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing with the Razor syntax two decimal values (1.00 and 3.00) in a JQuery function like so

```
  $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: @MinPrice,
        max: @MaxPrice,
        values: [@MinPrice, @MaxPrice],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            event = event;
            $("#amount").val("€" + ui.values[0] + " - €" + ui.values[1]);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            debugger;
            var path = "Shared/SideBar";
            $.ajax({
                url: path, type: "POST", cache: "false",
                dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'minPrice':'" + ui.values[0] + "', 'maxPrice':'" + ui.values[1] + "'}"
            });
        }
    });
```

which produces the following wrong html.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,00,
    max: 3,00,
    values: [1,00, 3,00],
```

The decimal separator is replaced with the comma character.
How can i fix that?

**Update**

As a workaround a changed the datatype of `MinPrice` and `MaxPrice` to string and converted it like so

```
MinPrice = MinPrice.ToString("0.00").Replace(",",".");
MaxPrice = MaxPrice.ToString("0.00").Replace(",",".");
```

and it works great at localhost. The problem is that now i do not know what will happen when the website goes live.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per MSDN [Decimal.ToString(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx) by default uses [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx). Your machine's default culture has ',' defined as the decimal separator. You can use another overload of ToString and provde an IFormatProvider. [Decimal.ToString Method (String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb(v=vs.110).aspx). The format provider you can provide is the [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
@{ string MinPriceString = @MinPrice.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   string MaxPriceString = @MaxPrice.ToString("0.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: @MinPriceString,
    max: @MaxPriceString,
    values: [@MinPriceString, @MaxPriceString],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        event = event;
        $("#amount").val("€" + ui.values[0] + " - €" + ui.values[1]);
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        debugger;
        var path = "Shared/SideBar";
        $.ajax({
            url: path, type: "POST", cache: "false",
            dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'minPrice':'" + ui.values[0] + "', 'maxPrice':'" + ui.values[1] + "'}"
        });
    }
});
```